# CSRF Guard:Owasp.CsrfGuard.js compilation error

Tags: csrf, owasp

I am trying to implement Owasp CARF library (3.0.0). When I place the Owasp.CsrfGuard.js file in WEB-INF/ folder and try to deploy the application, I get the below error:
Unexpected token % at Owasp.CsrfGuard.js

I see the %DOMAIN_STRICT% and other variables which are not recognized.
I have configured the Javscriptservlet like:

```
<servlet>
         <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
         <servlet-class>org.owasp.csrfguard.servlet.JavaScriptServlet</servlet-class>
         <init-param>
             <param-name>source-file</param-name>
             <param-value>/WEB-INF/Owasp.CsrfGuard.js</param-value>
         </init-param>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>inject-into-forms</param-name>
             <param-value>true</param-value>
         </init-param>
          <init-param>
             <param-name>inject-into-attributes</param-name>
             <param-value>false</param-value>
         </init-param>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>domain-strict</param-name>
             <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
             <param-name>referer-pattern</param-name>
             <param-value>.*</param-value>
        </init-param>  
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>JavaScriptServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/JavaScriptServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The server used is Weblogic 12.2.1.2

Do I need to configure anything. How do I resolve the js error??